# Auto-refreshing triggered by changes in directory for ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

I have a directory change monitor python script which monitors any changes happened in a directory, I want to trigger Arcmap auto refreshing whenever a change has been detected (eg. a new line added to a file). I tried to launch the monitor program within arcmap python command window using execfile("myprogram.py"). The problem I encountered is that once the script starts to monitor and auto-refresh, the arcmap main window was locked and frozen, no way to stop it except shutting down the arcmap, although I can see the auto-refresh happened whenever there is a change. Is there a way to run the monitor script in a separate process or background without locking or freezing the main window? Here is my monitor script which is borrowed from Tim Golden,

```
    import os
    import win32file
    import win32con
    import arcpy

    # Search for the new data
    ACTION = {
       1: "Created",
       2: "Deleted",
       3: "Updated",
       4: "Renamed from something",
       5: "Renamed to something"
    }


    FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY = 0X0001
    path_to_watch = "C:\Directory"

    hDir = win32file.CreateFile(
          path_to_watch,
         FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY,
         win32con.FILE_SHARE_READ | win32con.FILE_SHARE_WRITE |   win32con.FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
         None,
          win32con.OPEN_EXISTING,
          win32con.FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
          None
     )


     while 1:
        results = win32file.ReadDirectoryChangesW(
            hDir,
            1024,
            True,
            win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME |
            win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME |
            win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES |
            win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE |
            win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE |
            win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SECURITY,
            None,
            None
         )

    for action, file in results:
        full_filename = os.path.join(path_to_watch, file)
        print full_filename, ACTION.get(action, "Unknown")
        arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Comment: The problem is that they operate on different threads. ArcGis is *still* a single thread application and trying to influence it outside its thread is going to cause a problem. The best you could hope for is a timer event from ArcMap to pick up a boolean set by the Contents Changed event... to my knowledge python doesn't have delegate functions. If you're any good with C# I have a working example of something fairly similar - using Dynamic Display.

Comment: Is it possible to trigger the event outside arcgis? I have C# experience, would like to see your example, Thanks.

Comment: You can delegate it. I'll dig up the important parts of the code. I think though the best way around it is to use the Dynamic Display which comes with an OnTimerElapsed event (customizable, default 500ms I think)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the *absolute* nuts and bolts of the method:

```
IDynamicMap gDynamicMap;
IDynamicDisplay gDynamicDisplay;
FileSystemWatcher eLogWatcher;
bool gLOGchanged = false;

protected override void OnClick()
{
    IMap pMap = ArcMap.Document.FocusMap;
    gDynamicMap = (IDynamicMap)pMap;
    if (!gDynamicMap.DynamicMapEnabled) gDynamicMap.DynamicMapEnabled = true;
    gDynamicMap.DynamicDrawRate = (int)RefreshRate.Value; // set your refresh rate here
    
    // wire dynamic events
    ((IDynamicMapEvents_Event)gDynamicMap).DynamicMapFinished += new IDynamicMapEvents_DynamicMapFinishedEventHandler(OnTimerElapsed);
    ((IDynamicMapEvents_Event)gDynamicMap).AfterDynamicDraw += new IDynamicMapEvents_AfterDynamicDrawEventHandler(OnAfterDynamicDraw);
    
    // start the watcher
    eLogWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    eSnavWatcher.Path = BaseFolderPath.Text + "\\pos";
    eSnavWatcher.Filter = "*.log"; // set this or you'll get events for every file that changes
    eSnavWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite; // this too, limit the events
    eSnavWatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(eSnavWatcher_Changed);
    eSnavWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}
private void OnTimerElapsed(IDisplay Display, IDynamicDisplay dynamicDisplay)
{
    # do some processing in here, the map is already being refreshed
    # it is safe to do nothing here if !gLOGchanged - nothing to do.
    if (gLOGchanged)
    {
        # do your reading here
        gLOGchanged = false; // reset!
    }
}

void OnAfterDynamicDraw(esriDynamicMapDrawPhase DynamicMapDrawPhase, IDisplay Display, IDynamicDisplay dynamicDisplay)
{
    # draw graphics to the screen here
}

void eSnavWatcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    gLOGchanged = true;
}
```

The key here is the [DynamicMap](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//001200000435000000) and [DynamicDisplay](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//001w000000zv000000) which fires every [interval](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/DynamicDrawRate_Property/001200000436000000/) continuously. In order to draw graphics you need to use [DynamicSymbols](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/DynamicGlyphFactory_Property/001w0000010p000000/) (not standard symbols).

Using a [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) I set a boolean if a file is changed and then with the regular refresh detect that boolean indicating the file has changed. Note: with buffering the file may not change when you think it does, the FileSystemWatcher responds *only* when the file on disc has changed.

This code comes from a working tool that plots the course of a vehicle in real time (or near enough to) on a notebook to tell if the vehicle is going off course and correct before the data captured is invalid.

Comment: This solution can be made as an arc toolbox or a standalone exe? Thank you so much for the code, I will give a try on this solution!

Comment: It is best to create as an add-in (.esriaddin) http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Building_add_ins_for_ArcGIS_Desktop/0001000000w2000000/ Install Visual Studio (I have 2010) - see http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/get-started/system-requirements/arcobjects-sdk-system-requirements.htm (Express 2012 works) then install the SDK from your ArcGis install media.

Comment: My organization banned out the SDK and add-in development, so I have to wait for my license of SDK to implement the work.

Comment: That's lamentable Zheng, you can use ArcObjects in python but you still need the SDK installed... btw. what reason for not allowing it? Visual Studio Express is free (registration required) and there is no additional charge for the SDK (it's on your install media but it wont ask unless the installer detects a suitable VS - see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62720/how-to-learn-arcobjects-net-c-for-desktop-applications-but-having-only-arcm/75771#75771)

Comment: I have visual studio 2012 installed, but lack of ArcObject SDK. Is there free  version of ArcObject? Our arcgis installation follows a specific workflow, not the normal media installation, there is no Arcobject option there. Guess its for security reason.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85993/are-arcobjects-sdks-for-net-free-to-download has some instructions. If you have an Esri customer care account you can download from there. You will need to put a business case to your supervisors, that shouldn't be too hard as cost = $0 and being a major software company there shouldn't be any virus/nagware/spyware and the benefit is tools that *actually* work. There would be a steep learning curve so be prepared to offer to learn in your own time; if you need help GIS.SE is here 24/7 and the response time is quite good.

Comment: I was digging around and found a post I answered a long time ago which has another answer http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130273/adding-stathread-to-an-esri-addin/130334#130334 - according to Martin Wilkerson the System.Windows.Forms.Timer is synchronous so not a separate thread. If you're finding dynamic display too much this might be a bit simpler.